# Nested field ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm really new to the ruby on rails framework and i try to build a recipe website to learn more about this framework.

I have a entity Recipe.rb which has many RecipeIngredient. A RecipeIngredient is a entity in relation with a Ingredient, a Unit and have a quantity.

Here are the files :

**Recipe.rb**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Enumerize, FriendlyId

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :directions
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :directions, reject_if: :all_blank,   allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { thumb: "270x200#", main: "570x420#" },  default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  enumerize :difficulty, in: [:easy, :medium, :hard], default: :easy
end
```

**RecipeIngredient.rb**

```
class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :unit
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

**Ingredient.rb**

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe_ingredient
end
```

**Unit.rb**

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe_ingredient
end
```

As you can see, I use the gem Cocoon to handle nested fields. So, when the user wants to create a recipe, he has to provide the ingredients with the recipe.

My _form looks like this : (I have removed all html tag (the indentation is not good here)

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
  - if @recipe.errors.any?
    .alert.alert-danger
      - @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        li= msg
        = f.input_field :title, label: false, placeholder: 'Nom de la recette', required: true
        = f.input_field :prepareTime, label: false,  placeholder: 'Temps de préparation (en mn)', required: true
        = f.input_field :cookingTime, label: false, placeholder: 'Temps de cuisson (en mn)', required: true
        = f.input_field :difficulty, label: false, required: true, placeholder: 'Difficulté'
        = f.input_field :serves, label: false, placeholder: 'Nombre de personnes', required: true
        = f.input_field :description, label: false, placeholder: 'Description', required: true
    = f.simple_fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |recipe_ingredient|
      = render 'recipe_ingredient_field', f: task
      = link_to_add_association 'Ajouter un ingrédient', f, :recipe_ingredients, class: 'add'

    = f.simple_fields_for :directions do |direction|
      = render 'direction_field', f: task
      = link_to_add_association 'Ajouter une étape', f, :directions, class: 'add'

      = f.input_field :image, as: :file, label: false
    = f.button :submit, value: 'Ajouter la recette', class: 'button'
```

**_recipe_ingredient_fields.html.slim**

```
.f-row.ingredient
  .nested_fields
    .large
      = f.input_field :ingredient, label: false, placeholder: "Nom de l'ingrédient"
    .small
      = f.input_field :quantity, label: false, placeholder: 'Quantité'
    .third.mb
      = f.association :unit, label: false
    = link_to_remove_association '-', f, class: 'remove'
```

And last but not least, my recipe controller

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :find_recipe, only: [:show]

  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  def new
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.build
  end

  def create
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'La recette a été ajoutée'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :prepareTime, :cookingTime, :difficulty, :serves, :description, :image, directions_attributes: [:id, :step, :done, :_destroy], recipe_ingredients_attributes: [:id, :ingredient, :unit, :quantity, :done, :_destroy])
  end

  def find_recipe
    @recipe = Recipe.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

So now, when I tr to create a new recipe, I have an error "Ingredient excepted, String given".
I know it's because my new ingredient is not created in my create method but I really don't know how to do this. If someone can help me :)

Comment: "render 'recipe_ingredient_field', f: task`" - what is `task` here? Isn't this raising an error when rendering?

Comment: How. Yes. It has to be f: recipe_ingredient. I will try this at home and come back here. Thanks Sergio !

Comment: I fixed my mistake by replacing render 'recipe_ingredient_field', f: task by render 'recipe_ingredient_field', f: recipe_ingredient
But the error is still here : 
Ingredient(#70329373917340) expected, got String(#70329368504180)
At line : @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(recipe_params)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the ingredient in recipe_ingredients as a string then I think your issue is caused by a name clash between your model and the input field so rename your input field to something else and update your strong parameters.

However...If instead you intend to build a new ingredient record when you add a recipe_ingredient record then you need to have a fields_for clause in order to build the ingredient record and have it associated to your recipe_ingredient field. Also make sure than your recipe_ingredient includes accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients